# Object Oriented PHP Email Contact Form Not Sending

Tags: php, forms, oop

I have done quite a few contact forms in PHP no problem, however I'm very new to oop and I can't quite wrap my head around how this should work. I'm working with a tutor who is helping me self teach this, basically giving me resources to learn oop, but I'm stuck on this. I was to make a simple contact form that send the user info to the email specified on the same form. These were my requirements:

The User class should:

- Contain the relevant submitted data as properties of the class
- Have a constructor method that will let you declare the class and set the data in one statement

The Email class should:

- Be static
- Have a method that will let you send the email in one statement
- Have a method that will replace the formatting tags ([b] / [i] / [[name]]) with the proper equivalent
- Have proper access to the methods (private / public)

I'm not worried about the validation or syntax conversion right now as I just want to work through why the email isn't sending.

runner.php:

```
<?php
class User  {

public $firstName;
public $lastName;
public $toEmail;
public $fromName;
public $fromEmail;
public $subject;
public $message;

public function post() {
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$mail = new email($_POST['firstName'], $_POST['lastName'], $_POST['toEmail'],     $_POST['fromName'], $_POST['fromEmail'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']);
$mail->toEmail = $POST['$toEmail'];
$mail->sendMail();
    }
  }
}

class email {

private $fristName;
private $lastName;
private $toEmail;
private $fromName;
private $fromEmail;
private $subject;
private $message;

public static function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $toEmail, $fromName, $fromEmail, $subject, $message) {
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
    $this->toEmail = $toEmail;
    $this->fromName = $fromName;
    $this->fromEmail = $fromEmail;
    $this->subject = $subject;
    $this->firstName = $message;
}

 function sendMail($mail) {
    $contents = "To: $firstName&nbsp;$lastName<br />From: $fromName<br />Subject: $subject<br />Message: $message";
    $headers = "From:" . $fromEmail;
    $sendmail = mail($this->toEmail, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->contents, $headers);
    }
}
?>
```

form.html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="runner.php" method="POST">
<b>To</b></br>
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName"></br>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName"></br>
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="toEmail" id="toEmail"></br></br>
<b>From</b></br>
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="fromName" id="fromName"></br>
<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="fromEmail" id="fromEmail"></br></br>
<b>Compose Email</b></br>
[b]<b>bold</b>[\b] and [i]<i>italic</i>[\i] tags permitted in email body</br>
<label>Subject</label>
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject"></br>
<label>Body</label>
<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea></br></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't even know if I'm on the right track with this.  Any help/resources would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You have `$fristName` spelled wrong.

Comment: Well, you're never calling `post()` or `sendMail()`... Also, you defined 2 classes, but are never instantiating any of them. So nothing should happen. If you want to use the classes you defined, you need to first create instances of them, then call the methods on the instances you created. You will then start seeing a few pretty self-explanatory errors that should indicate what's wrong with the code.

Comment: You also have `$this->firstName = $message;`. Is this your actual code?

Comment: What a mess. you only need to use private and public once like this

`private $fromEmail, $subject, $message;`

Comment: @Connor, what a mess... Declaring all variables in a single line. (read as: "this is a personal style preference" from the "tabs vs spaces" category)

Comment: @j08691 (moved) nope no errors just nothingness

Comment: @MelissaMcVeigh, which is normal, since the code does not get executed.

Comment: `mail()` is being called wrongly. You're passing both `$this->message` and `$this->contents`, as well as the headers - you're not defining `$this->contents` anywhere.

Comment: @romo no it certainly is not. I have been at this since Saturday pretty much round the clock... I'm a little frazzled

Comment: @Connor I did initially have that but I wasn't sure if it was correct because in many of the tutorials I've watched/read they are all on separate lines.

Comment: Ok, well it is correct :)

Comment: Actually @rid i don't know if you noticed, but when you add your comment it's kinda TRIMMED?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think it's to do with your `$contents` variable. You've only set it within the `sendMail` class, but you used `$this->contents`. Try setting `private $contents;` as an instance variable, or just use `$contents` on this line:

```
$sendmail = mail($this->toEmail, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->contents, $headers);
```

(should be:)

```
$sendmail = mail($this->toEmail, $this->subject, $this->message, $contents, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are working in local, php mail function will not work.

Try to use phpmailer library(smtp) or try to upload script to hosting with mail enabled server.

Comment: It's possible to be working locally and have a mailserver set up, though.

Comment: yes you can do it with smtp settings for local. Try to use phpmailer library with html support too.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
class User  {

public $firstName;
public $lastName;
public $toEmail;
public $fromName;
public $fromEmail;
public $subject;
public $message;

public function post() {
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$mail = new email($_POST['firstName'], $_POST['lastName'], $_POST['toEmail'],     $_POST['fromName'], $_POST['fromEmail'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message']);
```

```
$mail->toEmail = $POST['$toEmail'];
```

`toEmail` is a private property. If you want to be able to set it like this, then it should be declared as public. Also, there is no `$toEmail` field in the HTML form you posted, so you probably want to write `toEmail` here.

Also, you already set this value in the constructor.

```
$mail->sendMail();
    }
  }
}

class email {
```

It is a general convention that classes should start with a capital letter, but this is mainly a style issue.

```
private $fristName;
private $lastName;
private $toEmail;
private $fromName;
private $fromEmail;
private $subject;
private $message;

public static function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $toEmail, $fromName, $fromEmail, $subject, $message) {
```

You cannot have static constructors... You should either make this a normal constructor, or, if you want the class to only contain static properties, then remove it altogether. If you want the properties to be static though, you should define them as such in the code above.

Also, if this must be a class containing only static properties, then you likely don't want to instantiate it.

```
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
    $this->toEmail = $toEmail;
    $this->fromName = $fromName;
    $this->fromEmail = $fromEmail;
    $this->subject = $subject;
    $this->firstName = $message;
}

 function sendMail($mail) {
    $contents = "To: $firstName&nbsp;$lastName<br />From: $fromName<br />Subject: $subject<br />Message: $message";
    $headers = "From:" . $fromEmail;
```

`$firstName`, `$lastName`, ..., are not available here, you probably mean to use `$this->firstName`, ..., etc.

```
    $sendmail = mail($this->toEmail, $this->subject, $this->message, $this->contents, $headers);
```

The `mail()` function may be disabled by the hosting provider. You should see an error message if that happens.

```
    }
}
?>
```

You're not instantiating any of these classes. You probably want to do something like:

```
$user = new User();
$user->post();
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed info - will go back and work on this, thanks again